# Button is not clickable in application and no selenium exception found in console

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to click on button(which I marked in yellow) using xpath, but it is failing to click and more over no selenium exception found. I tried to click with css selector and ID. Using  isdisplayed() - output is true. but with isselected() - output is false.

I Kept Webdriver wait (Visibility, element located, element to be clickable), implicit wait and explicit wait. But nothing is working out.

I'm new to selenium, please help me out

Below are the code

```
<button id="addNewButton-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" type="button" hidefocus="true" role="button" autocomplete="off" style="height: 19px;">
```

Comment: Below where?Please post your code and the html code.

Comment: I can see no code and also no HTML for it. It is always good to share the code and the HTML so that someone can help you.

Comment: HTML Code:<button id="addNewButton-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" type="button" hidefocus="true" role="button" autocomplete="off" style="height: 19px;">

Comment: //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#addNewButton-btnEl")));   wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.cssSelector("#addNewButton-btnEl")));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#addNewButton-btnEl")).click();

Comment: can you try this`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('addNewButton-btnEl').click();");` and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Its not clicking.

Comment: As per you advice, code is, wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("addNewButton-btnE‌​l")));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('addNewButton-btnE‌​l').click();");

Comment: Now my code is working, WebElement comp16 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#addNewButton-btnEl"));
    wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(comp16));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", comp16);